# RequireJS Optimizer - still attempting to load files from old dir - w/ Django

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

Need some help with the requireJS optimizer.
My setup is as follows:

- Django
- JS inside the Django static folder

Folder structure

```
- dist
    - copy of /static/ after optimizer (dir)
- django_app01
- django_app02
- django_app ...
- static
    - bower_components
    - js
```

What I'm doing:

1. Running r.js on the static folder.
2. r.js optmizes and moves the files to the "dist" folder as expected
3. Change the "static_url" settings in Django to get the static files from the "dist" folder.
4. Load the page and get a bunch of 404's as RequireJS is still trying to get modules from /static/...

Here's an example of the url's it's trying to fetch:
    localhost/static/...
Rather than
    localhost/dist/...

Any ideas why I'm getting all of these 404's after I run the optimizer. I expected the r.js optimizer to start to look for all the files in /dist.

build.js:

```
mainConfigFile : "static/js/require/common.js",
baseUrl: "static",
dir: "dist",
removeCombined: false,
findNestedDependencies: false,
modules: [
  {
    name: "js/require/common"
  },
  ...
]
```

common.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: '/static/',
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    ...
  },
  'shim': {
    'blah': {
      'deps': [...],
      'exports': 'blah'
    },
    ...
  }
})
```

html:

```
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/requirejs/2.1.14/require.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/require/common.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<script>
  require(['{% static "js/interviews.js" %}']);
</script>
```

Comment: If you are running this on localhost, `//cdn..` does not work - Change that to `http://cdn..`

Comment: I'm running a local server that resolves these urls. I double checked my network tab and this is getting resolved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what you do show in your question, the runtime configuration you use when you do not optimize your files is the *same* as the one you use after optimization. That is, you have only one `common.js` file that sets your runtime for both cases. This file sets a `baseUrl` of `/static/`, so that's where RequireJS looks for the files. The optimization process does *not* override this setting behind the scenes.

For a project of mine, what I did was to put the sources subject to optimization into a directory that is just for the source (`static-src`). Django does not know anything about this directory. Then either one of two things happen when I run `make` to build my project:

1. I make a non-optimized build which copies all the files from `static-src` to a directory named `build/static-build`. (There are other subdirectories for other purposes under `build`.
2. I make an optimized build which runs `r.js`. `r.js` puts its output in `build/static-build`.

In either case, everything ends up in the same location. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is set in my `settings` to grab files from this directory when `collectstatic` is run. My server is set to serve the `/static/` (the value of `STATIC_URL`) files from the location where `collectstatic` collected the static files.

This is just an example. You could use something else than `make`. You could certainly use different directory names. You could perhaps have a build process that is a bit simpler. (I created it when I was very new to Django and never bothered changing it.)

Comment: Will updated in a comment here with what my solution is. We're not using `make` so we'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Louis, your answer led me to my own solution which I feel works a bit better. See accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured out how to do this without using a watcher, or `make`, or any other folder copy script madness.

requireJS allows you to set default variables before you load your require.js lib at the top of your HTML.

Changes I made from my previous configuration are:
 - No longer define `baseUrl` in your module definitions (`requirejs.config`)
 - Define `baseUrl` as a default depending on the environment.

build.js:

```
mainConfigFile : "static/js/require/common.js",
baseUrl: "static",
dir: "dist",
removeCombined: false,
findNestedDependencies: false,
modules: [
  {
    name: "js/require/common"
  },
  ...
]
```

common.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  // baseUrl: '/static/', DO NOT DEFINE baseUrl here anymore
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    ...
  },
  'shim': {
    'blah': {
      'deps': [...],
      'exports': 'blah'
    },
    ...
  }
})
```

html:

```
<head>
    <!-- Define the baseUrl depending on environment -->
    <script>
        var require = {
            baseUrl: {% if debug %}'/static/'{% else %}'/dist/'{% endif %}
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/requirejs/2.1.14/require.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/require/common.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<script>
  require(['{% static "js/interviews.js" %}']);
</script>
```

Comment: What is best for any given project really depends on the project. I do need a build process anyway as a) there are other parts of my RequireJS runtime configuration that change depending on build conditions, and b) other files need processing during build. I also do not want to tie whether the optimized version is used to whether I'm in debug mode (`{% if debug %}`).

Comment: Yep, makes complete sense! My project is setup slightly different and this solution works better for it. I'm glad that there are two solutions to this issue.
I use `debug` extensively so it makes a bit more sense.